# How to parse a xhtml ignoring the DOCTYPE declaration using DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I face issue parsing xhtml with DOCTYPE declaration using DOM parser.

Error: 
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd%20

Declaration: DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd

Is there a way to parse the xhtml to a Document object ignoring the DOCTYPE declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that works for me is to give the DocumentBuilder a fake Resolver that returns an empty stream.  There's a good explanation here (look at the last message from kdgregory)

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5362097

here's kdgregory's solution:

```
documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver()
        {
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                throws SAXException, IOException
            {
                return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The parser is *required* to download the DTD, but you may get around it by setting the standalone attribute on the `<?xml... ?>` line.

Note however, that this particular error is most likely triggered by a confusion between XML Schema definitions and DTD URL's.  See http://www.w3schools.com/xhtml/xhtml_dtd.asp for details.  The right one is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: I used the same DOCTYPE. With the standalone attibute set to "yes" it still gives the same error. Below is my added on top my my xhtml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">

I still get the same error. java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd%20

Comment: You have a space beween the `.dtd` and the `"`

Comment: This seems to be a common issue as discussed in the blog, http://www.w3.org/2005/06/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to set validating=false in your DocumentBuilderFactory.  If you want to do validation, download the DTD and use a local copy.  As commented by Rachel above, this is discussed at [The WWW Consortium.](http://www.w3.org/2005/06/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic)

In short, because the default DocumentBuilderFactory downloads the DTD every time it validates, the W3 was getting hit every time a typical programmer tried to parse an XHTML file in Java. They can't afford that much traffic, so they respond with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the fake resolver, the following code snippet instructs the parser to really ignore the external DTD from the DOCTYPE declaration:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

(...)

DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
f.setValidating(false);
f.setAttribute("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
DocumentBuilder builder = f.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse( ... )
```