# DOM Parser freezes with an HTML having a DOCTYPE declaration

Tags: java, parsing, dom, freeze, doctype

This program reads two HTMLs from my site, and then parses each.
The first HTML (pass.html) does not have a DOCTYPE declaration in it.
pass.html parses normally.

The second HTML ([freeze.html](http://x19290.appspot.com/dom-no-good/freeze.html))
has a DOCTYPE declaration.
freeze.html is judged to be
[fully
valid](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fx19290.appspot.com%2Fdom-no-good%2Ffreeze.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)
by the validation service of W3C.
However, when I try to parse freeze.html, the program freezes at `.parse(is)`

What is wrong?

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

class DOMCallFreezes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new DOMCallFreezes().main();
    }

    void main() throws Exception {
        demo("pass.html");
        demo("freeze.html");
    }

    void demo(String htmlName) throws Exception {
        final String baseUrl = "http://x19290.appspot.com/dom-no-good/";
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl + htmlName);
        try (final InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
            final Document doc = newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
            final DOMSource src = new DOMSource(doc);
            final StreamResult dst = new StreamResult(System.out);
            newTransformer().transform(src, dst);
        }
    }

    DocumentBuilder newDocumentBuilder() throws Exception {
        final DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        return f.newDocumentBuilder();
    }

    Transformer newTransformer() throws Exception {
        final TransformerFactory f = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        return f.newTransformer();
    }
}
```

pass.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>pass</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>no DOCTYPE declaration</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

freeze.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>freeze</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>has DOCTYPE declaration</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Put `freeze.html` in the question. (If it's more than a few lines, remove things from it until you have something small enough that demonstrates the problem; see [mcve].)

Comment: You must call setEntityResolver() on the DocumentBuilder and provide a resolver that resolves your DTD locally. Otherwise the parse will attempt to download it from a web location that deliberately responds very slowly, causing your freeze. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640825/how-to-parse-a-xhtml-ignoring-the-doctype-declaration-using-dom-parser?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The following settings instruct the parser not to load the external DTD from the DOCTYPE declaration. Change the method `newDocumentBuilder()`:

```
DocumentBuilder newDocumentBuilder() throws Exception {
    final DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    f.setValidating(false);
    f.setAttribute("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    return f.newDocumentBuilder();
}
```